# Difference between Web Application and Worker Elastic Beanstalk tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there any difference between a Web Application vs Worker tier/environment?

As in if I were to deploy a web application will it work (not that I will do that, but am trying to understand whats the difference)? I imagine I can install my worker service on a Web Application instance and have my app connect to that. If so apart from the name difference, what other differences are there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the difference between worker-tier and web-tier in AWS beanstalk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302799/what-are-the-difference-between-worker-tier-and-web-tier-in-aws-beanstalk)

Answer (score 2):

According to AWS documentation of [How Elastic Beanstalk Works: Architectural Overview](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.architecture.html).

> When you launch an Elastic Beanstalk environment, you choose an
>   environment tier, platform, and environment type. The environment tier
>   that you choose determines whether Elastic Beanstalk provisions
>   resources to support a web application that handles HTTP(S) requests
>   or a web application that handles background-processing tasks. An
>   environment tier whose web application processes web requests is known
>   as a web server tier. An environment tier whose web application runs
>   background jobs is known as a worker tier. This topic describes the
>   components, resources, and architecture for each type of environment
>   tier.