# Running Flask port 80 on Elastic-Beanstalk Worker

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Given an AWS Elastic-Beanstalk Worker box, is it possible to use Flask/port:80 to serve the messages coming in from the associated SQS queue?

I have seen conflicting information about what is going on, inside an ELB-worker. The [ELB Worker Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html?shortFooter=true) page says:

> Elastic Beanstalk simplifies this process by managing the Amazon SQS queue and running a daemon process on each instance that reads from the queue for you. When the daemon pulls an item from the queue, it sends an HTTP POST request locally to http://localhost/ on port 80 with the contents of the queue message in the body. All that your application needs to do is **perform the long-running task** in response to the POST.

This SO question [Differences in Web-server versus Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43327794) says:

> The most important difference in my opinion is that worker tier instances do not run web server processes (apache, nginx, etc).

Based on this, I would have expected that I could just run a Flask-server on port 80, and it would handle the SQS messages. However, the post appears incorrect. Even the ELB-worker boxes have Apache running on them, apparently for doing health-checks (when I stopped it, my server turned red). And of course it's using port 80...

I already have Flask/Gunicorn on an EC2 server that I was trying to move to ELB, and I would like to keep using that - is it possible? (Note: the queue-daemon only posts messages to port 80, that can't be changed...)

The docs aren't clear, but it sounds like they expect you to modify Apache to proxy to Flask, maybe? I hope that's not the only way.

Or, what is the "correct" way of setting up an ELB-worker to process the SQS messages? How are you supposed to "perform the long-running task"?

**Note**: now that I've used ELB more, and have a fairly good understanding of it - let me make clear that this it *not* the use-case that Amazon designed the ELB-workers for, and it has some glitches (which will be noted). The standard use-case, basically, is that you create a simple Flask app, and hook it into an ELB-EC2 server, that is configured to make it simple to run that Flask app.

My use-case was, I already had an EC2 server with a large Flask app, running under gunicorn, as well as various other things going on. I wanted to use that server (as an image) to build the ELB server, and have it respond to SQS-queue messages. It's possible there are better solutions, like just writing a queue-polling daemon, and that no-one else will ever take this option, but there it is...

Answer (score 0):

The ELB worker is connected to an SQS queue, by a daemon that listens to that queue, and (internally) posts any messages to http://localhost:80. Apache is listening on port 80. This is to handle health-checks, which are done by the ELB manager (or something in the eco-system). Apache passes non-health-check-requests, using mod_wsgi, to the Flask app that was uploaded, which is at:

```
/opt/python/current/app/application.py
```

I suspect it would be possible but difficult to remove Apache and handle the health-checks some other way (flask), thus freeing up port 80. But that's enough of a change that I decided it wasn't worth it.

So the solution I found, is to change which port the local daemon posts to - by reconfiguring it via a YAML config-file, it will post to port 5001, where my Flask app was running. This mean Apache can continue to handle the health-checks on port 80, and Flask can handle the SQS messages from the daemon.

You configure the daemon, and stop/start it (as root):

```
/etc/aws-sqsd.d/default.yaml
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/sqsd/hooks/stop-sqsd.sh
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/sqsd/hooks/start-sqsd.sh
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/sqsd/hooks/restart-sqsd.sh
```

Actual daemon:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.3/bin/aws-sqsd
```

Glitches:
If you ever use the ELB GUI to configure daemon options, it will over-write the config-file, and you will have to re-edit the Port (and re-start the daemon).

Note: All of the HTTP traffic is internal, either to the ELB eco-system or the worker - so it is possible to close off all external ports (I keep 22 open), such as Port 80. Otherwise your Worker has Apache responding to http://:80 posts, meaning it's open to the world. I assume the server is configured fairly securely, but Port 80 doesn't need to be open at all, for healthchecks or anything else.